# Switch without break

Tags: java, switch-statement, findbugs

I have some switch statement as shown below. Notice there is no break.
Findbugs is reporting error on the second case statement only. 
The error is : Switch statement found where one case falls through to the next case.

```
switch(x) {

    case 0:
        // code

    case 1:
        // code

    case 2:
        // code
}
```

Comment: what does error message say ?

Comment: And the problem is...?

Comment: Are you sure it isn't a warning rather than an error?

Comment: I'm curious if it is unhappy because there is no "default:" in the above code.

Answer (score 109):

Findbugs is flagging up that falling through from one `case` to the next is generally not a good idea if there's any code in the first one (although sometimes it can be used to good effect). So when it sees the second `case` and no `break`, it reports the error.

So for instance:

```
switch (foo) {
    case 0:
        doSomething();
    case 1:
        doSomethingElse();
    default:
        doSomeOtherThing();
}
```

This is perfectly valid Java, but it probably doesn't do what the author intended: If `foo` is `0`, *all three* of the functions `doSomething`, `doSomethingElse`, and `doSomeOtherThing` run (in that order). If `foo` is `1`, only `doSomethingElse` and `doSomeOtherThing` run. If `foo` is any other value, only `doSomeOtherThing` runs.

In contrast:

```
switch (foo) {
    case 0:
        doSomething();
        break;
    case 1:
        doSomethingElse();
        break;
    default:
        doSomeOtherThing();
        break;
}
```

Here, only one of the functions will run, depending on the value of `foo`.

Since it's a common coding error to forget the `break`, tools like Findbugs flag it up for you.

There's a common use-case where you have multiple `case` statements in a row with *no* intervening code:

```
switch (foo) {
    case 0:
    case 1:
        doSomething();
        break;
    case 2:
        doSomethingElse();
        break;
    default:
        doSomeOtherThing();
        break;
}
```

There, we want to call `doSomething` if `foo` is `0` **or** `1`. Most tools won't flag this up as a possible coding error, because there's no code in the `case 0` prior to the `case 1` and this is a fairly common pattern.

Comment: Is `break` really necessary at the end?

Comment: @kcpr: Strictly speaking, you don't need a `break;` on the last case of a switch (`default` in the above). But I prefer consistency. It's purely a matter of style, the same bytecode is produced either way. (This isn't, of course, true if you leave off any *other* `break;`.)

Comment: This is a very good description of the common issue and how switch works, but doesn't really answer the OP's question - though, strictly speaking, the OP didn't actually present a question...

Comment: @Tasgall: How does it not answer the question? (Such as it is. :-) )

Comment: T.J.Crowder: The question - well, he didn't technically ask a question, but his situation and wording matches the question I was searching for at least :P - was how to make the findbugs tool not complain on an intentional fall through case. Your writeup on switch and why findbugs would flag it is very good and thorough, but doesn't show how to silence the warning if it was intentional. @L2M's answer below (adding "// fallthrough" or some variant where the "break;" would otherwise be) fixed it for me. Could you append that solution to your answer?

Comment: @Tasgall: L2M's answer is interesting, I always include a "fallthrough" comment as a matter of style. Are you saying having the comment there makes FindBugs not report the problem?

Comment: Why is this logical for java? Executing a case which statement is false just because a previous case was true?

Comment: @EmanuelGraf: It's just how `switch` statements traditionally work. Java inherited this from C. And note that if you have two case statements without a break, you're explicitly saying "Do this for either of the above," so it's not that you're executing code for a case that's false. It's that you're executing code for one of the two (or more) cases that you want it for. (C# modifies `switch` to only allow stacked `case` labels if there's no code between them.)

Comment: Just to add that you can avoid the `break` with other statements like `return doSomething()`, but it supposes you are inside a function body and you don't want to proceed with the code over the `switch-case` statement. So actually a specific context.

Answer (score 5):

I wrote these as comments but then it's not visible. I'm turning them into an answer. This is actually an extension to [T.J.Crowder's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8564008/644766).

You can find the related rule that causes Findbugs to report an error [here](http://findbugs.sourceforge.net/bugDescriptions.html#SF_DEAD_STORE_DUE_TO_SWITCH_FALLTHROUGH).

You can prevent Findbugs to report this kind of errors by creating an xml file with the following content, say `filter.xml` and running the tool with `-exclude filter.xml` option. See [filters on Findbugs](http://findbugs.sourceforge.net/manual/filter.html).

```
<FindBugsFilter>
  <Match>
    <Bug category="PERFORMANCE" />
  </Match>
</FindBugsFilter>
```

Comment: On Stack Overflow, it's actually perfectly acceptable to edit someone else's answer to add useful information (such as the above). Go for it!

Comment: @T.J.Crowder unfortunately my edits were rejected, I had to undelete my answer. Thanks for the suggestion anyway.

Comment: I suspect the actual rule was the more general [`SF_SWITCH_FALLTHROUGH`](http://findbugs.sourceforge.net/bugDescriptions.html#SF_SWITCH_FALLTHROUGH).  `SF_DEAD_STORE_DUE_TO_SWITCH_FALLTHROUGH` means, "not only was there a fall-through, but it clobbered something you had tried to save in a previous case".  That's much more likely to be a bug, in my opinion, so I would be much more hesitant to disable the `DEAD_STORE` rule than the `FALLTHROUGH` rule.

Answer (score 3):

Switch fall-throughs fall under the Findbugs category of "dodgy code". I think it only flags the first occurrence of a fall-through in a switch statement to cut down on the number of error messages.

Answer (score 2):

Without the break they will fall though into each other so if `x == 0` you'll go through all the code in every case statement block.  Findbugs could either be wrong about the error, or it could be an error condition without the break, i.e. something in `case 0` causes something in `case 1` to break.

Without the exact code and error I can't really help further.  Is the lack of breaks deliberate?

Answer (score 2):

Usually bug analysis tools don't like fallthrough in code because in most cases, the user has just forgotten to write the break.

I don't know if there is a way to specifically disable the warning with **FindBugs** but **Checkstyle** tool recognize special comments such as */* fallthrough */* to assume that the user really wants the following code to be executed. Putting this kind of comment also improves readability.
http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/config_coding.html#FallThrough

Java code convention also mentions the use of fallthrough comment.
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/codeconventions-142311.html

Answer (score 0):

If your cases don't have break, once a case is trigger switch will go through all cases until it finds a break or end of the cases. If you have default case it will trigger if your switch value in this case **foo** does not match with any other cases.

Answer (score -1):

Yes it is possible to use switch statement without break also. Only changes will be in syntax. For instance:

```
String fruit="Apple";
switch (fruit)
{
    case "Orange": System.out.println ("Orange");
    
    case "Apple":  System.out.println ("Apple");
    
    default:  System.out.println ("Invalid");
    
}
```

Using switch statement like this is called as enchaned switch

Comment: This is not how the enhanced switch introduced in Java 13 works.