# Switch Statement Buggy?

Tags: swing, switch-statement, java

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Switch without break](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8563970/switch-without-break)

I am making a small calculator app, and when the calculate button is clicked, a switch statement runs, but the number produced is not what It should be, I have tested my inputs and they do work here is the switch statement:

```
switch (currentOp) 
{
    case "+" : 
        answer = Float.toString(inp1 + inp2);
    case "-" : 
        answer = Float.toString(inp1 - inp2);
    case "X" : 
        answer = Float.toString(inp1 * inp2);
    case "/" : 
        answer = Float.toString(inp1 / inp2);
}
```

Comment: You forgot to break after each case.

Comment: If you're like me, whenever you think java is "buggy", stop, think again. 99.99% of the time, it's your (or my) understanding of Java that's buggy. Welcome to the club.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

See [case fallthrough](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/switch.html). If you don't break between each case, the next will be executed as well until a `break` is reached.

> The break statements are necessary because without them, statements in
>   switch blocks fall through: All statements after the matching case
>   label are executed in sequence, regardless of the expression of
>   subsequent case labels, until a break statement is encountered.

Answer (score 10):

Just an addition to the other answer, using polymorphism is usually preferred to switch cases:

```
public enum Operation {
    ADDITION {
        @Override
        public float compute(float a, float b) {
            return a + b;
        }
    },
    SUBTRACTION {
        @Override
        public float compute(float a, float b) {
            return a - b;
        }
    },
    PRODUCT {
        @Override
        public float compute(float a, float b) {
            return a * b;
        }
    },
    DIVISION {
        @Override
        public float compute(float a, float b) {
            return a / b;
        }
    };

    public abstract float compute(float a, float b);
}

...

answer = currentOp.compute(inp1, inp2);
```

Comment: I would like to learn this, anyone got any good articles on how to do this?

Answer (score 8):

You forgot to break so your case statements are falling through. Try this:

```
case "+" : answer = Float.toString(inp1 + inp2); break;
case "-" : answer = Float.toString(inp1 - inp2); break;
case "X" : answer = Float.toString(inp1 * inp2); break;
case "/" : answer = Float.toString(inp1 / inp2); break;
```

**Related documentation**

- [The switch statement](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/switch.html)