# How to move to next case in switch condition

Tags: android, random, switch-statement

I am in need of a code, using which in my Android App, I want to go through all  the cases of switch condition , (Not randomly!!!).I am able to move it randomly as follows.

```
public void switchingLogic(){
         Random rand = new random();
          int i = rand.nextInt(4)+1;
    switch (i) {
        case 1:
            setImages(R.drawable.ic_launcher, R.drawable.ic_launcher);
            selectedCorrectImage(img1, R.raw.correct_img, R.raw.thats_correct);
            selectedWrongImage(img2, R.raw.wrong_img, R.raw.no_its_wrong);
            break;
        case 2:
            setImages(R.drawable.ic_launcher, R.drawable.ic_launcher);
            selectedCorrectImage(img1, R.raw.correct_img, R.raw.thats_correct);
            selectedWrongImage(img2, R.raw.wrong_img, R.raw.no_its_wrong);
            break;
        case 3:
            setImages(R.drawable.ic_launcher, R.drawable.ic_launcher);
            selectedCorrectImage(img1, R.raw.correct_img, R.raw.thats_correct);
            selectedWrongImage(img2, R.raw.wrong_img, R.raw.no_its_wrong);
            break;
        case 4:
            setImages(R.drawable.ic_launcher, R.drawable.ic_launcher);
            selectedCorrectImage(img1, R.raw.correct_img, R.raw.thats_correct);
            selectedWrongImage(img2, R.raw.wrong_img, R.raw.no_its_wrong);
            break;
}
```

But now I want to just go in order from 1 through 4...

If the condition(Selected image) is correct in first case, I am showing Image in fullscreen and calling back the method again.

I just came across CURSOR .
Can I use it(if yes , How?) or is there any way I can solve this.
**Important: I Want to use this "Switching Logic method" in onCreate()**

Comment: in a switch case u will got only one value at a time..u have to do in side a loop..then check the condition inside the loop

Comment: means like for(i=0;i<4;i++){}   Also see the edited question.

Comment: Hi take a look at this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8563970/switch-without-break.

Comment: for(i=0;i<no_of_images;i++){if(match_here){}}

Comment: Why do you use a switch if you want to run all the cases? I really don't see what you are trying to do, you should explain more what you have in mind...

Comment: "If the condition(Selected image) is correct in first case, I am showing Image in fullscreen and calling back the method again." Like this I want to show all cases.

Answer (score 1):

If you dont set the `break` command in a switch-case, switch wont terminate after executing one case and move to the next one. so this code:

```
int i = 2;
switch(i) {
   case 1:
      // do something
   case 2:
      // do something
   case 3:
      // do something
```

}

will execute case 2 and case 3. Maybe you can implement an ifclause to define if the cases should break or not.

Answer (score 0):

You can try creating 2 methods to do this:

1. a method to loop through all cases by using a for loop
2. a method that contains your cases

Then just call

```
LoopThroughAllCases();
```

The code would look something like this.

```
    void LoopThroughAllCases()
    {
    int minCaseValue = 0; // modify to suit your case
    int maxCaseValue = 4; // modify to suit your case
    for (int i = minCaseValue ; i  <=  maxCaseValue ; i++)
                {

                    Cases(i);
                }
    }

    void Cases(int i)
            {
                switch (i)
                {
                    case 0:
                        // do something
                        break;
                      case 1:
                        // do something
                        break;
                      case 2:
                        // do something
                        break;
                      case 3:
                        // do something
                        break;
                      case 4:
                        // do something
                        break;
                      default:
                       //handle unknown value
                       break;

                }
            }
```