# Higher jump if player hold screen

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to have allow the user to press and hold the screen to increase the force of a jump (note `jspeed2`). I'm using the below code, but it doesn't do what I need.

Any suggestions?

```
case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: {
    if (x < 600 && jspeed2 < 28) { 
        jspeed2++; 
    }
}
case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP: {
    if (x < 600) { 
        player.jump();
    }
}
```

Comment: What does it do when it "doesn't work". It would also help to see more code, like the whole switch statment, where you declare jspeed2, and the jump() function.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Switch without break](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8563970/switch-without-break)

Answer (score 1):

You may want to add a `break;` line to your case statements.

Take a look at [this question's top answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8563970/switch-without-break) for more explanation.

Answer (score 0):

```
public final boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    float x = event.getX();
    int maskedAction = event.getActionMasked();
    if(GameState==0){
    graj=true;
    }

    if(GameState==1){
        switch (maskedAction) {

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:{if(x<600){player.jump();}   }

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:{if(x<600&&jspeed2<7){jspeed2++;}   }
}
        return true;
        }
    else return true;
    }
```

and that's how jumping looks:

> ```
>   public final void jump() {
>         if (jumped == false) {
>             sy = jspeed-GameView.jspeed2;
>             jumped = true;
>             l=20;
>         }
> ```

Comment: Underneath your question, there is an "edit" button. It would be better to put this code there than in its own answer. Currently, what is it doing that "doesn't work"?