# Why does java require a break inside a switch statement?

Tags: java, if-statement, switch-statement

A switch statement is basically a if, elif, elif, elif, elif, else.

Why does a switch statement need a break within it and an else if statement doesnt? What is the difference?

If, else if doesn't require a break.

```
if (c = 'a'){
     System.out.println("");
}
else if (c = 'b'){
     System.out.println("");
}
```

Switch statement requires a break.

```
switch(c){
case('a'){
     System.out.println("");
     break;}
case('b'){
     System.out.println("");
      break;}
}
```

Comment: You forgot to use`break;` in each case. See [Strings in switch Statements](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/language/strings-switch.html)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Switch without break](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8563970/switch-without-break)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to add `break` to each case,  e.g.

```
switch(choice){
   case 1:
     System.out.print("haha");
     break;
   case 2:
     System.out.print("aloha");  
     break;
}
```

Each break statement terminates the enclosing switch statement. Control flow continues with the first statement following the switch block. The break statements are necessary because without them, statements in switch blocks fall through: All statements after the matching case label are executed in sequence, regardless of the expression of subsequent case labels, until a break statement is encountered.

Comment: please replace brake with break and add some usuful link to give a definition about break it will complete your answer

Comment: If the issue was solved you should acept the answer :)